# How to get response text?

Tags: javascript, php

this is my register.js

```
var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("name", name.value);
    formdata.append("username", username.value);
    formdata.append("email", email.value);
    formdata.append("password", password.value);
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
var response = eval(ajax.responseText);
    alert(response);
    ajax.open("POST", "/req/register/register.req.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
```

and there is my register.req.php

```
require '../../inc/global.inc.php';
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);

    list($first_name, $last_name) = explode(" ", $_POST['name']);
    $db->query("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username, password, email) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", $first_name, $last_name, $_POST['username'], md5($_POST['password']), $_POST['email']);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('OK'));
```

And the question is how to get the 'OK' string, because var response = eval(ajax.responseText); gets just an 'undefinied' variable.

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!!!!!

Comment: nope because in class is solve that thing

Comment: you need to attach the `onLoad` or `onreadystatechanged` event to the xmlhttprequest. Just use this example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: var response = eval(ajax.responseText); end code.

Comment: Also, don't use eval. Just use `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the response in onreadystatechange method.

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
{
   if (ajax.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
      var response = ajax.responseText;
      alert(response);
   }
}
ajax.open("POST", "/req/register/register.req.php");
ajax.send(formdata);
```

Comment: My pleasure :)
. Accept this answer. Happy Coding.